# R Regression on Pearson father-son data

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm working on a school assignment and I am stuck on understanding how to do a few parts. Any help understanding and some sample code would be greatly appreciated. I'll post the code I have so far at the bottom of this post. Here is basically where I need help.

d) Add the SD line (with blue color, different from the regression line) to the same plot

This is what the professor provided to us for this

```
abline(a=a,b=b,col="blue", lty=4, lwd=3);
```

I just don't understand what the `a=a` and `b=b` is and what needs to be put in its place.

e) Mark the center of regression

f) Add horizontal and vertical lines (green color) through the center of regression

Code so far:

```
install.packages("UsingR");
library(UsingR);
data(father.son);
plot(father.son$fheight, father.son$sheight, xlab="Father's height (in)", ylab="Son's height (in)", xlim=c(58,76), ylim=c(58,80), pch=20)
abline(lm(father.son$sheight ~ father.son$fheight), lty=1, lwd=2)
```

Comment: I assume the a=a and b=b are to be changed to something other than a and b on the right hand side of the equation. As for what are a and b, you can type ?abline in R and it will bring up the R documentation for abline.

Answer (score 0):

How does this look? I'm still pretty novice to R so just wanted some feedback if I did it correctly.

```
abline(a=lm(formula = father.son$sheight ~ father.son$fheight),b=sd(father.son$sheight)/sd(father.son$fheight),col="blue", lty=4, lwd=3)
    abline(h = mean(father.son$sheight), col = 3)
    abline(v = mean(father.son$fheight), col = 3)
```